# Sort by label pulling emails with label already removed

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to pull content from an email and for some reason my code is pulling multiple emails, previously evaluated emails even though the label has been removed. I am looking to have this run and grab content from the body of the email and store it to then send a reminder email later. The issue I have is that the emails the script will be reading all have the same email subject line. The automated system cant change this (BOO!). Any ideas on how to get around this? Thanks guys!

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("SMI-054");
  var threads = label.getThreads();

  var millisPerDay = 1000*60*60*24;
  
  for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++)
  {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    //var date = threads[i].getLastMessageDate();
    
    Logger.log(threads.length);
    Logger.log(messages.length)

    for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++)
    {
      var msg = messages[j].getBody();
      var sub = null //messages[j].getSubject();
      var dat = Utilities.formatDate(messages[j].getDate(), "EST", "MM-dd-yyyy");
     
      var dateTest = Moment.moment(dat).toDate();
      dateTest = new Date(dateTest.getTime() + millisPerDay);

      var string = " ";
      string += dateTest;
      
      
      
      var msgSplit = msg.split("/");
      Logger.log(msgSplit[7])
      
      var string2 = msgSplit[7];
      string2 = string2.split(",")
      
      Logger.log(string2)
      ss.appendRow([string2[1], string2[2],string2[3]])
      threads[i].removeLabel(label);
    
      //ss.appendRow(["Recieved Date: " + dat, sub, "Modified Date string: " + string, sub, "Modified Date Object: " + dateTest])
      //ss.appendRow([msgSplit])
      
     // Logger.log(msgSplit)
      //MailApp.sendEmail("yourEmailHere", "test email back", "this is a test" + string + " beep boop")
    }
      //threads[i].removeLabel(label);
    
  }
}
```

Comment: It can take a while for labels to be updated. If I understood correctly, do all these emails have the same subject but different labels?

Comment: The emails have the same labels and the same subject line. I was reading and one thing I saw was the email ID, not sure if it is possible to use this to sort the emails. Thank you!

Comment: So you are basically trying to get the body out of these emails that have that specific label and subject line right?